How to use the OnPlatform structure in MAUI?
we are migrating an app from XAMARIN to MAUI.
We have this XAML here:
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="View">
    <OnPlatform:ios>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource StandardColor}" Padding="15,5,15,3" Orientation="Horizontal" IsVisible="{Binding Modal}">
            <Button Text="Annulla" FontSize="Small" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="Transparent" HorizontalOptions="Start" Command="{prism:GoBack UseModalNavigation=True}"/>
            <Label Text="Comunicazione" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
            <Button Text="Salva" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="Transparent" HorizontalOptions="End" Command="{Binding SalvaComunicazioneCommand}"/>
            <Button Text="Rimuovi" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="Transparent" HorizontalOptions="End" Command="{Binding RimuoviComunicazioneCommand}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </OnPlatform:ios>
    <OnPlatform.Android>
        <StackLayout>

        </StackLayout>
    </OnPlatform.Android>
</OnPlatform>

Visual studio does not recognize the OnPlatform:ios or OnPlatform.Android how can we now edit that XAML to have fixed? thanks

While both answers below (at the time of writing) should yield the correct result, it's worth to note that OnPlatform is evaluated at runtime, which means that the full code is still shipped for each platform.

I think this syntax has been obsoleted even during the Xamarin lifecycle. This should be the replacement:
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="View">
    <On Platform="iOS">
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource StandardColor}" Padding="15,5,15,3" Orientation="Horizontal" IsVisible="{Binding Modal}">
            <Button Text="Annulla" FontSize="Small" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="Transparent" HorizontalOptions="Start" Command="{prism:GoBack UseModalNavigation=True}"/>
            <Label Text="Comunicazione" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
            <Button Text="Salva" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="Transparent" HorizontalOptions="End" Command="{Binding SalvaComunicazioneCommand}"/>
            <Button Text="Rimuovi" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="Transparent" HorizontalOptions="End" Command="{Binding RimuoviComunicazioneCommand}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </On>
    <On Platform="Android">
        <StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </On>
</OnPlatform>

Read more about it on Microsoft Learn.
Note that you also might want to look into the specialized HorizontalStackLayout or VerticalStackLayout while you're at it.

You can use OnPlatform in this way to show/hide something based on platform:
<StackLayout IsVisible="{OnPlatform iOS='true', Android='false'}">
    <Button Text="Annulla" FontSize="Small" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="Transparent" HorizontalOptions="Start" Command="{prism:GoBack UseModalNavigation=True}"/>
    <Label Text="Comunicazione" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
    <Button Text="Salva" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="Transparent" HorizontalOptions="End" Command="{Binding SalvaComunicazioneCommand}"/>
    <Button Text="Rimuovi" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="Transparent" HorizontalOptions="End" Command="{Binding RimuoviComunicazioneCommand}"/>
</StackLayout>


In MAUI, the syntax for <On Platform="iOS"> </OnPlatform:iOS> has been updated to <On Platform="iOS"> </On>.
so your code should be:
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="View">
    <OnPlatform:ios>
        ...
    </On>
    <OnPlatform.Android>
        ...
    </On>
</OnPlatform>

Since the official documentation doesn't announce this change yet, you can try creating a default MAUI project to test this.
